# "Cannot load optional framework class" error when running Spring Native with GraalVM

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

Using Spring-native (Spring-boot3.0.5), I am trying to override `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner` class, but I get a runtime error when using AOT.

I define a new class that extends `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner`:

```java
lang=java

public class RpcComponentScanner extends ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner {

    public RpcComponentScanner(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        super(registry);
    }

    public void registerDefaultFilters() {
        this.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(MyRPCService.class));
    }

    public Set<BeanDefinitionHolder> doScan(String... basePackages) {
        Set<BeanDefinitionHolder> beanDefinitions = super.doScan(basePackages);
        return beanDefinitions;
    }  

 // ....... other codes
}
```

and implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`; this class will invoke `RpcComponentScanner.scan()` when spring application startup.

```java
@Component
public class RpcComponentProcesser implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

   @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        String basePackage ="com.demo";// value is "com.demo"
         
        if (!(beanFactory instanceof BeanDefinitionRegistry)){
            return;
        }

        RpcComponentScanner scanner = new RpcComponentScanner((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory);
        scanner.setResourceLoader(applicationContext);

       scanner.scan(RpcConstants.COMMA_SPLIT_PATTERN.split(basePackage));// This line runs success in JVM,but failed in AOT.The code compile successful with graalvm,but startup with exceptions 
    }

 // ....... other codes

}
```

I have registerd `RpcComponentProcesser` and `RpcComponentScanner`, `MyRPCService` in `RuntimeHints` class, which implements `RuntimeHintsRegistrar`.

The detailed exception log is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load optional framework class: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:206) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:258) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at com.tplink.ignite.rpc.processer.RpcComponentProcesser.postProcessBeanFactory(RpcComponentProcesser.java:61) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:358) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:201) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at com.tplink.ignite.platform.cms.CmsApplication.main(CmsApplication.java:48) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1132) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:202) ~[na:na]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
16:37:41.885 [main] INFO  c.t.i.p.c.bootstrap.SpringTrigger - ......... server start error.........
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load optional framework class: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:206) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:258) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at com.tplink.ignite.rpc.processer.RpcComponentProcesser.postProcessBeanFactory(RpcComponentProcesser.java:61) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:358) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:201) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at com.tplink.ignite.platform.cms.CmsApplication.main(CmsApplication.java:48) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1132) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:202) ~[na:na]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
16:37:41.895 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load optional framework class: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:206) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.scan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:258) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at com.tplink.ignite.rpc.processer.RpcComponentProcesser.postProcessBeanFactory(RpcComponentProcesser.java:61) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:358) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:201) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:6.0.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:3.0.5]
        at com.tplink.ignite.platform.cms.CmsApplication.main(CmsApplication.java:48) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1132) ~[nbs-bootstrap.exe:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:202) ~[na:na]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

When I remove this line:

```java
scanner.scan(RpcConstants.COMMA_SPLIT_PATTERN.split(basePackage));
```

The application run successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` requires runtime features like reflection and dynamic proxy generation.

First, I'd try using the GraalVM tracing agent, and if it doesn't help, you can try replacing it with another `BeanPostProcessor` from spring native.

For more:

- [InfoQ — Go Native with Spring Boot and GraalVM](https://www.infoq.com/articles/native-java-spring-boot/#:%7E:text=build%20time%20and%20run%20time%20processors)